# How do I update my firmware after installing a 400XL kit on my Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, 400xl

I've updated my Ender 3 with V4.2.7 mainboard, BLTouch and 400XL kit (extends the capabilities of your Creality Ender 3 3D Printer to a 400 mm X, 400 mm Y and a 500 mm Z printing platform). Now I need to update the firmware. YouTube did not provide any help: i.e.: out of date, so cryptic as to be unusable. Marlin & Creality had overly complicated, for what I need, solutions. Trying these led only to frustrations! Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing exactly which Youtube videos you've looked at, I think where I would start is by downloading the latest Marlin Fimrware and configuration files for the Ender 3 with 4.2.7 board:

[Latest Release of Marlin Firmware on Github](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/archive/2.0.x.zip)

[Configuration File Repository on Github](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/tree/release-2.0.7.2/config/examples/Creality/Ender-3%20V2)

[Microsoft visual Studio](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

[PlatormIO](https://platformio.org/install/ide?install=vscode)

If I were doing your upgrade in your place, I would refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neS7lB7fCww&t=495s) for how to compile the firmware for the correct board. I've had to compile firmware for my Ender 3 a few times and I sometimes forget a step. This video is the best that I've found for showing/reminding me of each step.

Essentially, what I think you need to do is compile your firmware as if it were a stock Ender 3 V2 using the settings files I linked above but then change your print area the configuration.h file to match the X400 x Y400 x Z500 print bed area.

Look for the following:

```
// The size of the print bed
#define X_BED_SIZE 200
#define Y_BED_SIZE 200
```

Change to the following:

```
// The size of the print bed
#define X_BED_SIZE 400
#define Y_BED_SIZE 400
```

And then look for

```
#define Z_MAX_POS 200
```

and change to:

```
#define Z_MAX_POS 500
```

There are other changes you'd need to make to the settings file (refer to the video for those). I haven't done your particular upgrade on my machine, so I'm just guessing those extra couple of changes would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the board upgrade on my Ender 3 Pro. As I've read the BLTouch is easy to install. I'd go over to the Creality [forum/help](https://forums.creality3dofficial.com/) site. You can open a support ticket.  They actively have information on firmware in both "release" and "beta" threads.  Look there & see if you can get your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after my post I found [this commercial Marlin site](https://marlin.crc.id.au/) <sup>*1)*</sup>. It offers firmware for Creality & other printers. You can order 'off the shelf' firmware or customize it yourself. Customizing is quite easy & self explanatory; 5 min. after submitting my requirements, I received a zip file, which I un-zipped & copied the needed file to my SD card. Then I inserted the SD card into my printer & started it. The printer recognized the new firmware & updated its self.

---

<sup>*1)*</sup> *This service is not free. Membership of \$15.00/year, is required.*

Comment: You have to have a yearlong membership for a one-time download?

Comment: Many thanks for answering your own question. Getting someone else to do the configuration for you is also an option which I myself never considered. But, for those on a tight budget, there are multiple sources that deliver the correct configuration for the Ender 3, the only difference is the larger printer volume dimensions, this is covered in [this answer](/a/15957). Please consider the other answers before accepting one. Thanks, happy printing!

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is obtaining a pre configured configuration file for this custom extended version of the Ender 3. While it should be very easy to find configurations for Ender 3 with or without BLTouch, the only difference this extension has is an updated printer volume specification. A ready made configuration is found [here](https://github.com/teachingtechYT/Marlin/blob/Ender3-V2-BLtouch-extender/Marlin/Configuration.h) (please note that it contains an errand for the maximum build height, change `#define Z_MAX_POS 250` to `#define Z_MAX_POS 500`.

The basic changes are:

```
// The size of the print bed
#define X_BED_SIZE 400
#define Y_BED_SIZE 400

Z_MAX_POS 500
```